# Get custom attribute from LDAP and map into keycloak

Tags: attributes, ldap, keycloak, mapper

we are using synchronize function to get all users from LDAP into keycloak. I want to get custom attribute "User logon name" which is available in LDAP.
mapper setting which is already done is getting username, first name, last name, mail.
how do i change mapper setting to get "User logon name" from LDAP and save it into username field of keycloak.?
i have performed following steps but no luck:

1. changed mapper "LDAP attribute = "User logon name"
2. synchronize all users

any guideline would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to map a field called  "User logon name"  from LDAP into a field called username in Keycloak. Try the following:

- Go to Realm where the LDAP is configured;
- Go to User Federation;
- Select the LDAP in question;
- In the Setting tab set the field "Username LDAP Attribute" to "User logon name";
- Click `[Save]`;
- The switch the tab to Mappers;
- Select username;
- edit "LDAP Attribute" to "User logon name"
- Click `[Save]`; and tried it out.