# How to use keycloak and AD to implement contextual RBAC model?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, authorization, keycloak, rbac

In my case users can have roles (eg store_admin, operator, etc) and extra context attached to the role (eg store, region, etc).

For example John has role store_admin and context {store:123}. This means that inside CMS he can access all functionality related to store administration (CMS knows about role and attaches permissions to it), but only for store=123, every other store will be filtered out, and direct access will be denied.

Right now this custom authorization system is part of our own CMS, but we are trying to move this auth part to separate components: keycloak as auth server, AD for storing users and roles/groups, and ERP for managing users and roles.

And now I'm stack and can't figure out elegant solution for managing roles.

The only thing that come to mind is to use really long parsable groups/roles name inside AD (eg role-cms-store_admin-store_123), then keycloak will sync this roles and pass to CMS via JWT after successful authentication, and then CMS will parse role and extract real role and related ctx. But AD has group name size and characters limits, so it will be risky to implement. I can use separate storage for ctx and use IDs inside AD group names, but it's also extra level of complexity.

Maybe roles with context are not the best way to restrict access to some objects...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could give a shot to [Custom attributes in Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow) and on keycloak side use ['user-attribute-ldap-mapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990705/get-custom-attribute-from-ldap-and-map-into-keycloak)

Comment: It will not help with my current use case, because dynamic context/attributes are linked to roles, not users. On the other hand right now I'm trying to convince stakeholders that we don't really need such overcomplicated authorization, and we should switch either to vanilla RBAC, or RBAC with user attributes (similar to what your are proposing). In both cases integration become trivial, so I'm crossing my fingers 

Comment: Ahah I am crossing the fingers with you because I totally agree ..